# Parse Android-SDK crashed on initialize

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-gradle-plugin

I've simply went over the tutorial for storing data on Parse and received:

> "Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

What did I do:

1. Copy 'Parse-1.9.1.jar' into my lib directory (Android Studio, have successfully integrated other SDKs)
2. Added the following lines to my 'build.gradle' dependencies:

   - compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'bolts-android-*.jar')
   - compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
3. Added the following lines to my 'OnCreate' function:

   - Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
   - Parse.initialize(this, ______ , _______);
4. App crashes with error:

> Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class
>   java.lang.Class com.parse.OfflineStore$32

Comment: Did you create separate class that extends Application and pasted the 3rd point code there? not on activity onCreate.

Comment: It probably has to do with where you are storing your data I your code not how you set it up

Comment: Thanks @YuvaRaj that was the issue - make it an answer and I'd select it.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate class that extends `Application` and do the Parse Initialization and enabling database stuff there. Should be like,

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxx", "xxx");
    }
  }
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml, add ParseApplication class to Application

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.parsetry.ParseApplication" // you should replace this based on your package
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```